# Metamask sent ETH frommy Ethereum chain to my ETh account on Optimism chain

Tags: ether, metamask

Metamask: I sent ETH from my Ethereum chain account to my ETH account on Optimism chain. Are the ETH automatically again in my Metamask Ethereum chain account?

Comment: Hi Alex! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Metamask is just a wallet. Check the addresses balances with a block explorer.  Even though Optimism and Ethereum use the same type of addresses they are on different blockchains. You need to use a bridge to exchange ether/tokens between different blockchains. You can share the transaction hashes if you want a more detailed answer.

Comment: 0x42285c3df7006a40a09e59ae93b0c058a11c70ed7950b983ebd6f80928c7a86a

Answer (score 0):

The transaction [0x42285c3df...](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x42285c3df7006a40a09e59ae93b0c058a11c70ed7950b983ebd6f80928c7a86a) does *nothing*. It transfer ether from a contract to itself on Ethereum mainnet. It didn't transfer anything to the Optimism blockchain, but you didn't lose any of the ether that should remain in the wallet.

To transfer from mainnet to another blockchain like Optimism you have to use a bridge. Check the page about bridges on the optimism network https://www.optimism.io/apps/bridges.

Comment: ok great! thank you